# How to "see" the refund of SELFDESTRUCT?

Tags: solidity, selfdestruct

I am trying with hardhat to simulate and see the gas refund. Here is my 2 smart contracts for testing purpose:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;



contract DaughterContract{
   function destruct()public {
        address payable addr = payable(address(msg.sender));
        selfdestruct(addr);
    }

}

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract TestContract {

 
 DaughterContract public lastSMBuilt;

uint256 myNum=0;

function createSmartContract() public returns (DaughterContract) {
     DaughterContract daughter = new DaughterContract();
     lastSMBuilt=daughter;
     return daughter;
}

function destroy() public {
     lastSMBuilt.destruct();
}

 function expensiveTxWithDestroy() public {

  destroy();
    for(uint i=0; i<1995;i++){
       myNum=i;
    }
    }
}
```

1/ I call createSmartContract
2/ Then I call  expensiveTxWithDestroy

If I comment the  **destroy** call inside **expensiveTxWithDestroy** the overall cost in gas is lower. So refund is not happening. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gas refunds for `selfdestruct` were removed with [EIP-3529](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3529) which was included in the [London hardfork](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md) in 2021. Not seeing a refund for `selfdestruct` is expected behavior.

Comment: Why were Gas refunds removed with EIP-3529? Weren't they implemented to free up Network space?

Comment: It is well explained in link above: avoid exploit.

Comment: @DannyB That is why they were implemented, yet, but practically speaking gas refunds for selfdestruct was not encouraging the freeing up of network space. It was encouraging the speculation on gas prices (in an extremely inefficient manner) via GAS tokens

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately they removed gas refunds because it was filling the blockchain with space-consuming gastokens and transactions just to get some cheap gas back, which is not liked by ethereum developers.

In my opinion it should have been kept because it helped people use some cheap gas, but that's no longer possible.